# schießen auf vs anschießen

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning or usage between "[schießen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schie%C3%9Fen) auf" and "[anschießen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anschie%C3%9Fen)" ? I can see none in the first (main) definition of both verbs in DWDS.

Example:

- Er schoss auf den Dieb.
- Er schoss den Dieb an.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- auf jemanden schießen
  means to shoot at somebody
  *Er schießt auf den Dieb.*
- jemanden anschießen
  means the bullet hits the body
  *Er schießt den Dieb an.*
- jemanden erschießen
  the target is dead
  *Er erschießt den Dieb*.

Comment: Note that anschießen usually implies that the target survived the initial shooting. [US-Polizisten bei Protesten angeschossen](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/anklage-fall-breonna-taylor-103.html). It is mentioned that they are hospitalized.

Comment: Technically, those forms express a contrast in [telicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity).